# Display array of database record inside Repeater using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to display last 3 images which are present inside `sqlserver` on the view page using c# asp.net.I am using repeater for displaying the view.In the below code i am using repeater.

> index.aspx:

```
<section class="slider" id="slider">
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImageId"  >
                    <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:9;slidedelay:7000;">                    
                        <img src="pic/medical-slide-1.jpg" alt="" class="ls-bg">

                        <div class="intro ls-l" data-ls="offsetyin:top;offsetxin:0;durationin:2000;offsetyout:bottom;offsetxout:0;durationout:1000;" style="left:80%;top:35%;">
                            <span class="icon fa fa-heart"></span>
                            <h2><span>SYMPTOM</span>CHECKER</h2>
                            <p>Vestibulum rutrum luctus porta. Maecenas elit nibh</p>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Read More</a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
                    <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:40;slidedelay:7000;">               
                        <img src="pic/medical-slide-2.jpg" alt="" class="ls-bg">

                        <div class="intro ls-l" data-ls="scalexin:0.3;scaleyin:0.3;rotatexin:180;offsetxin:0;durationin:2000;durationout:2000;scalexout:2;scaleyout:2;offsetxout:0;fadeout:true;showuntil:3000;" style="left:80%;top:35%;">
                            <span class="icon fa fa-comments"></span>
                            <h2><span>HELP</span>ONLINE</h2>
                            <p>Vestibulum rutrum luctus porta. Maecenas elit nibh</p>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Read More</a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
                    <div class="ls-slide" data-ls="transition2d:11;slidedelay:7000;">
                        <img src="pic/medical-slide-3.jpg" alt="" class="ls-bg">

                        <div class="intro ls-l" data-ls="skewxin:30;skewyin:0;offsetxin:right;fadein:false;durationin:2000;durationout:1000;offsetxout:right;offsetyout:0;fadeout:true;" style="left:80%;top:35%;">
                            <span class="icon fa fa-flask"></span>
                            <h2><span>LAB</span>TESTING</h2>
                            <p>Vestibulum rutrum luctus porta. Maecenas elit nibh</p>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Read More</a><!--
                                --><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</asp:Repeater> 
                </section>
```

In the above code there are 3 image present (`i.e-medical-slide-1.jpg,medical-slide-2.jpg,medical-slide-3.jpg`).I need to set the last 3 images from database in those 3 places.How i will do this in `index.aspx.cs` page inside page_load event.My table name is `T_Banner` and i am using sqlsever.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: How are you retrieving the records from database. Can you give your sql query or stored procedure?

Comment: @ hpatel : I want to retrieve last 3 value of `Image` column present inside `T_Banner` table and display all 3 image in the proper place which i have explained above.I want to do this inside page_load method.

Comment: @user5011580 's solution should work for you requirement. Please give you full code including page_load code, sql query as well as the table structure.

Comment: its throwing the error as `Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' does not have a public property named 'div'.` after adding div inside repeater.

Comment: that div should go inside <ItemTemplate> inside <Repeater>

Answer (score 1):

This query might solve your problem:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Image_Column FROM T_Banner ORDER BY Image_Column DESC
```

You might need to use ORDER BY according to your need

using Eval in the view:

See this example:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb7c7ffd-f5f0-476c-a4ee-35b3364bf3ed/how-to-bind-repeater-with-images-in-table-column-?forum=adodotnetdataset

no need to put three divs inside repeater, just one is enough.
repeater with bind it three times based on select statement.

Comment: @ user5011580 : Ok Then how i will display them on view.

Comment: Yes thats true but inside each set of div there are some different text so how this will be managed.

Comment: those different text should also come from the database, may be create a column for that text. Could you send the full code for your page including code behind?